# How can I solve this error "The current path, Logout, didn't match any of these."

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Am creating a user login form and logout, when I run the code I get error which says "The current path, Logout, didn't match any of these."

I have tried to go through the code again and again it looks Ok but still I get the same error, i don't know where the problem is. tried to look for different examples it looks fine but still i get the same error

*views.py*

```
# logout view
def logout_request(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "Logged out successfully")
    return redirect("main:homepage")


# login view
def login_request(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = authenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        username = form.cleaned_data('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data('password')
        user = authenticate(username, password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as{username}")
            return redirect("main:homepage")

form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request,
              "main/login.html", 
              {"form":form}
              )
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path( "", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path('logout/', views.logout_request, name='logout'),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),  
]
```

LOGIN TEMPLATE

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
   <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button class="btn"type="submit">login</button>
</form>
If you already have an account, <a href="/registe> 
 <strong>register</strong></a> instead
{% endblock %}
```

TRACEBACK

[image]

Comment: try `https://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/` with `/` at the end.

Comment: SHOW YOUR TEMPLATES

Comment: It works only with logout when I add "/ " but when i come to the page it doesn't work and with login it is not working at all @Gasanov

Comment: @Kelvin when you come to which page? With login what error does it produce? Provide full code, including templates

Comment: Also your login view doesn't really login people, just render `AuthenticationForm`. Just use [default LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) or rewrite it to handle POST

Comment: @gasanov sorry for the delay, with login it still give me the same error but with logout if I use "http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/" as you suggested it works. Please help am stack!!

Comment: If it gives you `The current path, Login, didn't match any of these.”`, add `/` at the end or remove `/` from your `urlpatterns`. Otherwise, provide full traceback and url that you actually tried. Your `urls.py` configured correctly.

Comment: I appreciate for your help, I have tried to both remove and add it but still no changes, have added the traceback and url